# Why does the type of local variables that are values affect the type of input variables in the type signature of a function?

Tags: haskell

```
Prelude> func f = [(show s, f == s) | s <- [0, 1..10]]
Prelude> :type func
func :: (Num a, Enum a, Show a, Eq a) => a -> [(String, Bool)]
```

I would expect `f` to just be an instance of `Eq a` but all the class constraints applied to `s` are also applied to `f` for some reason. Replacing `s` with any constant removes the relevant type constraint for `f`, and replacing `s` in the equality removes all class constraints except `Eq a` for `f`.

Can someone explain to me why does the type of local variables that are values affect the type of input variables that are values?

Comment: As an aside: `[0..10]` is a slightly shorter version of `[0,1..10]`, and quite idiomatic. Technically they are allowed to mean slightly different things, but in practice, almost every type with the associated instances makes them the same -- certainly all the types that come with the compiler do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Eq` doesn't exist in a vacuum. To compare two things for equality, you have to have *two* things. And, crucially, those two things have to be of the same type. In Haskell, `0 == "A"` isn't just false; it's a type error. It literally doesn't make sense.

```
f == s
```

When the compiler sees this, even if it knows nothing else about the types of `f` and `s`, it knows what `(==)` is. `(==)` is a function with the following signature.

```
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

Both arguments are of the same type. So now and forevermore, for the rest of type-checking this expression, we *must* have `f` and `s` of the same type. Anything required of `s` is also required of `f`. And `s` takes values from `[0, 1..10]`. Your type constraints come as follows

- `Num` is required since `s` takes values from a list of literal integers.
- `Enum` is required by the `[..]` list enumeration syntax.
- `Show` is required by `show s`.
- `Eq` is required by the `f == s` equality expression.

Now, if we replace `s` with a constant, we get something like

```
func f = [(show s, f == 0) | s <- [0, 1..10]]
```

Now `f` is being compared with `0`. It has no relation to `s`. `f` requires `Eq` (for `(==)`) and `Num` (since we're comparing against zero, a number). `s`, on the other hand, requires `Enum`, `Num`, `Eq`, and `Show`. In the abstract, this should actually be a type error, since we've given no indication as to which type `s` should be and there aren't enough clues to figure it out. But [type defaulting](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html) kicks in and we'll get `Integer` out of it.